# Spain Visa Extension

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, spain, business-travel, visa-extensions

I'm from India. I applied for a business visa to Spain for 90 days. I got the Visa approved with Multiple visits. But it's been approved only for 30 days. I need to be there for another 1 month for my Business trip. Why did this happen and could I extend my Visa after reaching Barcelona?

Comment: A visa run To a nearby country?

Comment: @AyeshK What? I'm sorry. But I didn't understand as to what you were trying to suggest to solve my issue here.

Comment: So you got a Schengen visa for 30 days. What is the validity period? Is it only 30 days or does it allow you to stay within Spain for at most 30 days in a given longer period? I am asking because it is typically not possible to have two visa with overlapping validity dates at the same time.

Comment: Multi entry visas generally have a max-stay condition even if it's valid for a long time. 1 year multi entry visa could have a condition so that you can't stay in the country for more than a month per visit. As I understand, you have a multi entry visa with a max 39 day stay, you can easily get around this restriction by visiting a nearby country and coming back the very next day.

Comment: @AyeshK It's valid from 11/1/2015 to 24/02/2015 for 30 days. But I need to be there till March 6th.

Comment: @DCTLib It's valid from 11/1/2015 to 24/02/2015 for 30 days. But I need to be there till March 6th.

Comment: What was the reason given for approving a shorter period than what you applied for? Have you verified with the issuing consulate if they have made a mistake?

Comment: @AyeshK It does not work that way at all. A visa valid for more than six months generally should not have any restriction beyond the general 90 days in any 180-day period limit. Other restrictions are *total* number of days during the whole visa validity, not limits on the duration *per visit*.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Why and how would they give a reason? There is a form (and a whole procedure) for refusals but if they do issue a visa, they just hand you your passport with a sticker in it.

Comment: @dishoom Have you been in the Schengen area before (and in particular in the last couple of months)?

Comment: @Relaxed I was actually telling about visas in General. OP said its a multi entry visa.  However, multientry visa do work that way for some sort. I apply for a Malaysian multi entry visa(3 months, 39 days per stay), and I can technically stay there for 87 days total if I make a quick visit to Singapore on every 29th day and come back the next day. It wouldn't work for Schengen though. OP said Spain visa and 30 days, so I thought he's not going to use a Schengen visa.

Comment: @AyeshK As Spain is a member of the Schengen area, nearly all short-stay visas issued by Spain will be regular uniform type C Schengen visas. But it's true the OP did not explicitly mention it.

Comment: Guys, I haven't been to any other country previously. This is the first time I'm travelling outside my country.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking consulates from Schengen countries can issue what they deemed appropriate, you can't apply for a “90 days visa” or a “30 days visa” or anything like that. So if you submitted an itinerary for a business trip with meetings spread over ten days, you might receive a visa covering only that and you can't expect to get some sort of standard visa that would allow a longer stay.

If you did however submit a longer itinerary with all the necessary documentation, it's also possible they simply made a mistake. You can always try to ask them to reconsider (informally, as there is a procedure to complain about refusals but nothing if you did get a visa).

In any case, you can't generally extend a short-stay visa from within Spain (there are some exceptions but they won't apply to your situation).

Comment: Can i ask them to reconsider to extend my visa after going to barcelona? is there no way for me to get an extension after going to Spain? I did give my itenary that clearly stated that I will be there till March 6th. Over got meetings spread all over in February.

Comment: @dishoom Usually it's not possible, you should try to contact the consulate as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm leaving tonight to Spain and Consulate is closed today.

Comment: I found this answer at https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110416135710AAKu9As

There's a point that says:
Examples of serious personal reasons justifying an extension of a visa:
- an Angolan businessperson has travelled to Italy to negotiate a contract with an Italian company and to visit several production sites in Italy. Negotiations take longer than expected and the Angolan national has to stay one week longer than intended.

Comment: @dishoom Yes, that's the kind of things that can justify an extension according to the *Handbook for the processing of visa application and the modification of issued visa* published by the EU Commission. That's what I alluded to in the last paragraph of my answer but the problem is that in your case there is no unexpected change, you are leaving knowing full well that you want to stay longer. You could get lucky but there is no reason for the Spanish authorities to grant you an extension in this situation.